# How to write classical Hamiltonian $H = \frac{I^{2}}{2}$ in $(p,q)$ variables?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, anharmonic-oscillators

Suppose I have a completely integrable $1$ degree of freedom Hamiltonian $H(I, \varphi) = \frac{I^{2}}{2}$ written in action-angle variables $(I, \varphi) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{S}$.

What would the corresponding Hamiltonian be in canonically conjugated variables $(p,q)$, and the corresponding example of the physical system it describes?

Naturally we are looking for some kind of an oscillator (since all orbits are periodic) but with frequency depending on $I$ (the amplitude).

Comment: There is no unique answer to this question as posed , in the sense that the Hamiltonian for many systems can be reduced to this form using suitable canonical transformations.

Comment: What would be a good example of such a system? Some kind of anharmonic oscillator? @ZeroTheHero

Comment: the usual harmonic oscillator.

Comment: But for the usual harmonic oscillator, the typical Hamiltonian is $H = I$ and frequency $\omega(I) = 1$ (say after normalisation of constants), i.e. does not vary with action. What I specify is that in my case, frequency varies with action $I$ (I need this for application of KAM theory etc) @ZeroTheHero

Comment: P.S. in general, for KAM theory one needs nondegenerate frequencies; the Hamiltonians of the form $H = \frac{I^{2}}{2}$ also arise in so-called apriori unstable systems as models for Arnol'd diffusion @ZeroTheHero

Comment: 1. If you have something specific in mind please clarify your question.  2. I don't see how you can get degenerate frequencies with only 1 p and 1 q.  3. If you need an analytically-solvable example try $V(q)=U \tan^2(\alpha q)$ for positive $U$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: 1. What one typically needs for KAM is the nondegeneracy condition $\mbox{det} \frac{\partial^{2} \omega}{\partial I^{2}} \neq 0$, which is not satisfied for a simple harmonic oscillator. 2. I think a Hamiltonian like $H(p,q) = (p^{2} +q^{2})^{2}$ works, as when transferred to action-angle variables, it becomes $H = I^{2}$ @ZeroTheHero

Comment: You don't understand "nondegeneracy" condition in the sense I do (i.e. all $\omega$'s different).  Regardless, I think $V(q)=U\tan^2(\alpha q)$ will give you what you want.